# Difference between using "Null Propagation Operator" with JSRender in Browser vs on Node App

Tags: node.js, jsrender

When I use the null propagation operator on a template with jsrender in the browser and again on a node application, I get different behavior. The template renders correctly in the browser, but when I use it on the node app, it returns a syntax error.

This is the example I have:

```
export const render = (template: string, data: any): string => {
  jsrender.views.settings.allowCode(true);
  jsrender.views.settings.debugMode(true);

  template = `{{*: data.animal?.name || "Bob" }}`;

  let tmpl = jsrender.compile(template);

  return tmpl(data);
};
```

and this is the error that it throws on the node app:

```
2020-08-20T08:16:34.280Z    947a4602-aab6-1cf5-f28b-d867efa16560    INFO    Error
    at /var/task/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:221:27
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:2964:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/dist/utils/jsrender.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30) {
  name: 'JsRender Error',
  message: 'Syntax error\n' +
    'Compiled template code:\n' +
    '\n' +
    '// unnamed\n' +
    'var v,ret="";\n' +
    '\n' +
    'ret+=  data.animal?.name || "Bob" ;\n' +
    '\n' +
    'ret=ret;\n' +
    'return ret;\n' +
    `: "Unexpected token '.'"`
}
```

Comment: This may be because I am using AWS's nodejs12.x runtime